# Loop function not returning right result in R

Tags: r, function, loops, google-places-api, google-places

I have created a function below with to grab google data from the places api. The input is the google url with api key, and is supposed to return a dataset of the places searched for. But for some reason the dataset is only returning with the same iterations of data ( ie the same places over and over). If I run though line by line manually it works correct so I'm a little stuck. I think maybe it has something to do with the return value.

So the function calls the api and creates a dataset(ds), and then grabs the next page key(page token) as google only sends 20 values at a time. It then runs the loop adding the next page key to the URL and puts that into a new dataset (ds_new) and then combines that data with the old though an rbind(ds,ds_new). This loop continues until the next page key == NULL or runs for ten iterations. Then return the dataset (ds)

Any tips or help would be appreciated.

```
google_key_places <- ###############
search_type <- "bar"
lat_long <- "-27.502870962086018,153.03244147954413"
radius <- "6000"    #in meters 
pagetoken <- ""
url <- paste0("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?",
              "location=",lat_long,
              "&radius=",radius,
              "&type=",search_type,
              "&key=",google_key_places)
```

```r
get_google_places <- function(url){
  
    doc <- getURL(url)                       # Grabs the URL data
    x <- jsonlite::fromJSON(doc)
    ds <- cbind(x$results$geometry$location, # lat and long
                x$results$name,              # Name of Business
                x$results$vicinity,          # Address of Business
                x$results$price_level,       # Price Level (1 Cheapest - 5 Most Expensive)
                x$results$rating,            # Google Ratings
                x$results$user_ratings_total,# Total User Ratings
                x$results$place_id)          # Google ID Code
    pagetoken <- x$next_page_token
    
    for (i in 1:10){ 
      url_new <- paste0(url,"&pagetoken=",pagetoken)
      doc <- getURL(url_new)
      x <- jsonlite::fromJSON(doc)
      ds_new <- cbind(x$results$geometry$location, # lat and long
                  x$results$name,              # Name of Business
                  x$results$vicinity,          # Address of Business
                  x$results$price_level,       # Price Level (1 Cheapest - 5 Most Expensive)
                  x$results$rating,            # Google Ratings
                  x$results$user_ratings_total,# Total User Ratings
                  x$results$place_id)          # Google ID Code
      pagetoken <- x$next_page_token
      ds <- rbind(ds,ds_new)
      if (is.null(pagetoken)){
        return(ds)
      }
    }
    
    return(ds)
  
}
```

Comment: I like @Pake's answer for some of the recommendations, but I don't know that there is enough information here for those of us without google api keys to be able to know for certain what is going on. It might help to look at the responses in a little more detail. For instance, in the loop, post the outputs of `url_new`, `str(ds_new)`, and `pagetoken`, and then same for the next iteration of the loop. (I don't think more than two is necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

I would try these generalized steps:

1. Make a list.  We first simply name the list something that makes sense to you:

   `google_stuff<-list()`
2. Next,  in defining your output, within the loop, you use `[[]]`.  Essentially, you are making a list item in `google_stuff` for each of your 10 loops through.  So, in basic form, you'll now have:

   ```
   google_stuff<-list()
   for (i in 1:10){
   url_new <- paste0(url,"&pagetoken=",pagetoken)
   doc <- getURL(url_new)
   x <- jsonlite::fromJSON(doc)
   ds_new <- cbind(x$results$geometry$location, # lat and long
              x$results$name,              # Name of Business
              x$results$vicinity,          # Address of Business
              x$results$price_level,       # Price Level (1 Cheapest - 5 Most 
                                                             #Expensive)
              x$results$rating,            # Google Ratings
              x$results$user_ratings_total,# Total User Ratings
               x$results$place_id)          # Google ID Code
    pagetoken <- x$next_page_token


    google_stuff[[i]]<-ds_new
   ```

   }
3. Finally, you can use `dplyr::bind_rows(google_stuff,ds)` to get a nice dataframe with all the data you've pulled.

   ```
   all_my_google_stuff<-dplyr::bind_rows(google_stuff,ds)
   ```

Comment: Since there's no preceding use of `dplyr`, an alternative to `bind_rows` is `do.call(rbind, google_stuff)`. Note that this would need to bring in the first `ds`, since the code here is just on `ds_new`.

Comment: Regardless, I suggest you should add either `dplyr::` before the call, or a preceding `library(dplyr)`, since it is neither suggested in the OP nor clearly identified in your answer.